# Unable to locate jar file in DB2 Command prompt

Tags: jar, command-prompt

I am trying to create a User Defined Functions in IBM data studio, I am following the steps at this [Link](https://newpush.com/2009/08/creating-a-user-defined-function-udf-in-java-for-ibm-db2-9-7/).

I did not have any problem until the step where I have to Register the jar file with DB2 by entering:

```
db2 "CALL sqlj.install_jar('C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk
\bin\udftest.jar','UDFTESTJAR')"
```

Into DB2 Command Prompt. However it shows the following error:

```
SQL20200N  The install or replace of "BELSIZE .UDFTESTJAR" failed as
"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk\bin\udftest.j" could not be
located. SQLSTATE=46001
```

I have check through the location of udftest.jar, I am sure that the location path was correct. May I know what is wrong with me command line? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After looking true the website link again, I have forgotten to add file: at the path.

```
db2 "CALL sqlj.install_jar('file:C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk
\bin\udftest.jar','UDFTESTJAR')"
```